# Having a background without moving the letter's position

Tags: html, css

I want to add a button background to the "a" without moving its position.

The table B is almost correct except that you move the "a" the right side.

I don't know how to do it.

You also need to take account to the I also need to change the size of the width in the future.

Thanks!

```css
    #testtesttesttest {
        width: 50px;
        background-color: #F1F2F2;
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #47a417;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1px 8px;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 21px;
        color: white;
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    }

    #testtesttesttest:hover {
        background-color: #3D8E14;
    }
 
 ul.aa, ul.bb
 {
  list-style-type: none;
 }
```

```html
 Table A:

 <ul class="aa">
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    a
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    b
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    c
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    d
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    e
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>

 <br/>
 <br/>

 Table B:
  
 <ul class="bb">
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    <span id="testtesttesttest">a</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    b
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    c
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    d
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    e
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: If you remove `text-align: center;`?

Comment: @Harry and add `text-align: right;` - if you want see your text in right side

Comment: Sorry Harry, the position is the same.

Comment: add `margin-left: -30px;` to move it back

Comment: @HelloWorld You've received a number of answers at this point - if none of them meet your needs, you're probably going to need to edit your question to further clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give negative left margin

```css
    #testtesttesttest {
        width: 50px;
        background-color: #F1F2F2;
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #47a417;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1px 8px;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 21px;
        color: white;
        font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        margin-left:-30px;
    }

    #testtesttesttest:hover {
        background-color: #3D8E14;
    }
 
 ul.aa, ul.bb
 {
  list-style-type: none;
 }
```

```html
 Table A:

 <ul class="aa">
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    a
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    b
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    c
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    d
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    e
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>

 <br/>
 <br/>

 Table B:
  
 <ul class="bb">
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    <span id="testtesttesttest">a</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    b
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    c
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    d
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    e
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the span to inline-block doesn't help so change that to inline. Then remove the 8px padding and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to remain in the same place but also keep it centered inside the background, you could shift it back with a CSS transform (equal to width/2 - horizontal padding/2):

```
#testtesttesttest {
    transform: translateX(calc(-50% + 4px));
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x943stnb/1/) to show the effect. Try changing around the width, and you'll see the text still stays in the same place. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.